# How to use a LIKE query with CodeIgniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-like

I want to run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%search_term%'
```

In CI you can bind parameters to queries, if you used `field=?` but this does not work for `field LIKE "%?%"`. From debugging output it seems the query used is `field LIKE "%'search'%"`.

Is there an alternative way to do searching in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE ?
```

And bind with `%search%` instead of `search`.

You should be aware that this query will be slow in MySQL. You might want to look at free-text search instead (Lucene, Sphinx, or MySQL's built-in free-text search functions).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. This isn't for a major part of my script so the speed isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2):

this is active record class for codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->like('columnname','both');
$query=$this->db->get("tablesname");
$result=$query->result_array();
if(count($result))
{
return $result;
}
else
{
return FALSE;
}
```

You should try this..I think its help you..
both means %columnname%,
before means %columnname,
after means columnname%

Answer (score 1):

```
$search_term=$this->input->post('textboxName');
$search_term="%".$search_term."%";
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE ? ";
$query=$this->db->query($sql,array($search_term));
$res=$query->result();
```

Comment: yes. It is a answer for a situation where string in like clause. But i was struggled with a query where variable in Like clause. It doesn't work if you define it as %variable_name% . I found a solution. That's why I answered.

Answer (score 0):

what i can understand CI is adding quotes, pass FALSE as third parameter while binding to prevent CI adding quotes.